# How to define multiple providers using @PactTestFor

Tags: java, junit5, pact

We are using PACT library for contract testing. Current project relies on junit5 integration. I have to extend one test to use 2 providers instead of 1:

Current version:

```
    @Test
    @PactTestFor(providerName = "request-repository", hostInterface = "0.0.0.0", port = "9991")
    public void myTestMethod() throws Exception {}
```

I read doc: https://docs.pact.io/implementation_guides/jvm/consumer/junit5 and it seems to be not supported yet:

> Unsupported#
>
> The current implementation does not support tests with multiple providers. This will be added in a later release.

I checked the release notes and I haven't found any updates. Is there another way how to define another provider? ie something as:

```
    @Test
    @PactTestFor(providerName = "request-repository", hostInterface = "0.0.0.0", port = "9991")
    @PactTestFor(providerName = "result-repository", hostInterface = "0.0.0.0", port = "9992")
    public void myTestMethod() throws Exception {}
```

Or in this case junit5 integration is not a good choice?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

My suggestion would be to write 2 separate tests, where each test has one provider mocked via Pact and the other provider stubbed out (e.g. with a standard unit test stub).

Comment: Thx for the suggestion. It seems to be pretty easy to do.

Comment: That suggestion though doesn't work if you are testing a single business logic method that as part of its flow, talks to 2 providers, whose config is static (i.e. the port to use is defined before the test class executes).